# How to create a composite resources in one Table

Tags: ms-access-2013

Please help me how to create a table for composite resources cost in MsAccess database. Example:

```
    Composite Excavator Cost =
    Excavator basic cost + Operator composite cost+ fuel cost

While

    Operator composite cost= operator basic cost+ accommodation cost+ food allowance
```

And so on. Some resources composites require multi levels of basic and composite resources.
Thanks
Salim